# Python 2.7/Tkinter ¿Cómo se cambia de una clase a función normal?

Tags: python, tkinter

como siempre tengo varias preguntas. He buscado incluso ejemplos en inglés pero no he encontrado la solución. Encontré este ejemplo de cómo dibujar un rectángulo dentro de un canvas con sólo hacer clic y arrastrar el ratón, lo cual funciona muy bien. Pero forma parte de una clase (con eso de .self):

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=512, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

        self.rect = None

        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None


        self._draw_image()


    def _draw_image(self):
         self.im = Image.open('imagenfondo.jpg')
         self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
         self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)



    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        if not self.rect:
            self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, fill=None, outline="black")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)



    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo hacer que todo este código deje de ser una clase y sea una función normal de Tkinter?
No hay mucha información sobre esto de las clases.
Tal vez los entendidos me quieran matar por lo que escribiré a continuación, pero así se aprende: intenté quitando todos los .self y def__init del inicio etc. pero no funciona y me da error.
Es justo lo que necesito pero no lo quiero dentro de una clase aún.
Y otra cosa más, una vez creada dicha función, cuando ya esté dibujado el rectángulo ¿cómo hago referencia a él? Es decir, crear luego otra función que llame a dicho rectángulo ya dibujado sin importar su tamaño o posición en el canvas o a sus coordenadas. ¿Debo llamar a rect, a canvas.rect, draw.image o a canvas.create_rectangle? Todo esto lo quiero utilizar para un pequeño programa editor de imágenes. De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El siguiente código es una versión usando funciones del código que muestras

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def on_button_press(event):
    # save mouse drag start position
    global rect, x, y, start_x, start_y, canvas
    start_x = event.x
    start_y = event.y
    # create rectangle if not yet exist
    if not rect:
        rect = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, 1, 1, fill=None, outline="black")


def on_move_press(event):
    curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

    # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
    canvas.coords(rect, start_x, start_y, curX, curY)


def next_image(event):
    canvas.move(item, 10, 0)


def on_button_release(event):
    pass


root = Tk()
root.title()
x = y = 0
rect = None

start_x = None
start_y = None

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=512, height=512, cursor="cross")
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
im = Image.open('imagenfondo.jpg')
tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
item = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=tk_im)
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", on_button_press)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_move_press)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_button_release)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)
root.mainloop()
```

Le añadi una función que cada vez que aprietas el botón izquierdo del mouse la imagen se mueve.

Las funciones de la forma `canvas.create_XXX` retornan un número que identifica al objeto creado, este sirve para manipularlo despues.

Salida Inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida despues de apretar varias veces el botón izquierdo del mouse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Aunque ahora falta saber cómo llamar o hacer referencia al rectángulo. Me hubiera gustado alguna explicación, pero el ejemplo funciona.

Comment: @Toño ya actualize mi respuesta, no vi necesario dar una explicación ya que los cambios son intuitivos y no existe una regla para hacer ello.

Comment: @Toño te recomendaría que te mires la POO (programación orientada a objetos) y la pongas en practica. Las interfaces gráficas se simplifican mucho usandola, si tu app se va complicando la programación estructurada te complica la vida. Ya estas usando clases sin saberlo (en Python todo son objetos de hecho), `root = Tk()` es una instancia de la clase `Tk `por ejemplo.

Comment: @FJSevilla comparto tu opinión :P